# Render Props - need to execute function after some component configuration

Tags: reactjs

UPDATE,  SOLUTION FOR NOW:

I moved `scopes` to the `state` and now the `scopes` data is up to date.

---

I am using render prop with the new context API. To make it easier, lets say that API got two methods. Method A is used by ChildComponent via Context API, and `methodB` is used as render prop.

The problem is that I need on init below order:

1. `ChildComponent` runs `methodA` from context API
2. `Component` property: `this.scopes` is populated
3. When `methodB` runs (from render props), it knows about `this.scope`

For now, `methodB` runs before the `this.scope` is populated (`this.scope = {}`) by `methodA`

I tried with `setTimeout`, but I don't think it is the best idea...

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    scopes = {};

    render(){
        const api = {
            methodA: (name, fields) => {
                this.scopes[name] = fields;
            },
            methodB: (name) => {
                console.log(this.scopes[name])
            }
        }

        return (
            <ComponentContext.Provider value={{ api }}>
                {typeof children === 'function' ? children(api) : children}
            </ComponentContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

/************* CHILD COMPONENT */
class ChildComponent extends React.Component{ 
    static contextType = ComponentContext;

    componentWillMount() {
        const { api } = this.context;

        api.methodA(name, this.fields);
    }

    render() {
        const { children } = this.props;

        return children;
    }
}

/************* COMPONENTS IMPELENTATION WITH THE PROBLEM */
<Component>
    {(api) => (
        <ChildComponent name="foo"> // it should at first add foo to the Component this.scope;
            <div>Some Child 1</div>
        </ChildComponent>
        <ChildComponent name="bar">  // it should at first add bar to the Component this.scope;
            <div>Some Child 2</div>
        </ChildComponent>

        {api.methodB(foo)} // not working because for now this.scopes is empty object (should be: {foo: someFields, bar: someFields})
    )}
</Component>
```

I expect to result `this.scope = {foo: ...someFields, bar: ...someFields }`, for now `this.scope= {}` after initial run, next invocation of `methodB` works okey, and  (`this.scope = {foo: ...someFields, bar: ...someFields}`.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: You should provide a complete, minimal and verifiable example

    [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You add and use the scope in the same lifecycle, thus using the old version of passed context. You can move your `api.methodB(foo)` from `Render()` method to `componentDidUpdate()` step, which will ensure you have a new context when it executes.

Comment: Thank you for response. I decided to put `scopes` outside the `state` because it won't change after first initialization. But moving `scopes` to the  `state` solves the problem :) I think I will stick to this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In case the initialization occurs only once and synchronously, parent `Component` can be considered initialized when it is mounted.

If the purpose of `methodB` is to return data that a parent was initialized with, parent's state should be updated on initialization. It's an antipattern to store component's state outside `this.state`. There may be a flag that definitely indicates that the initialization was completed:

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    state = {
        scopes: {},
        init: false,
        methodA: (name, fields) => {
            if (this.state.init) return;
            this.state.scopes[name] = fields;
        },
        methodB: (name) => this.state.init ? this.scopes[name] : null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
       this.setState({ init: true });
    }

    render(){
       return (
          <ComponentContext.Provider value={this.state}>
            ...
          </ComponentContext.Provider>
       );
    }
}
```

This way `api.methodB(foo)` will return `null`, unless the initialization is completed.

Comment: Thank you for response. I decided to put `scopes` outside the `state` because it won't change after first initialization. But moving `scopes` to the  `state` solves the problem :) I think I will stick to this implementation.